# Where is the created MySQL database folder stored in Mac OS X?

Tags: mysql, macos

Where is the created MySQL database folder stored in Mac OS X?

Comment: What does a filesystem have to do with a paper publication? What does MySQL have to do with MAC addresses?

Comment: @BoltClock he is probably referring to an Apple MacBook. Mac OS X is a Unix-based system

Comment: @OM I don't know where the data files are located on OS X. The best thing to do would be to run a `find` search for one of your database names (on the console, not the normal OS X search)... Update: @Álvaro has it.

Comment: @Pekka: *Knew* I was misreading the question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Run this query:

```
SELECT @@datadir, @@innodb_data_home_dir
```

The exact files and or subfolders depend on the exact database name and table types.

Comment: Thanks for the query Álvaro González

Comment: In Terminal, issue the `mysql` command and then type `select @@datadir;`

Answer (score 12):

For me, it's in `/usr/local/var/mysql`.

Answer (score 3):

mysql is found in /usr/local/mysql. Databases are stored in the data folder (/usr/local/mysql/data/*databasename*). This may be different depending on how you installed it.

Answer (score 1):

I installed mysql (Ver 8.0.31 for macos13.0 on arm64) using Homebrew 3.6.12 the databases are stored here `/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/`